# IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 16, Size: 17?

Tags: android, rx-java, indexoutofboundsexception, android-messaging

I get a very odd index out of bounds exception unlike any other i have received. It says the index is 16 and size is 17 and still crashes?
Here's the code where it crashes:

```
public void subscribe(@io.reactivex.annotations.NonNull ObservableEmitter<Pair> observableEmitter) throws Exception {
    for (int i = 0; i < messages.size(); i++) {
        MessageInterface mi = messages.get(i);
        if (mi != null
                && (mi.getMsgTimestamp() <= message.getMsgTimestamp()
                || (mi.getMsgTimestamp() < message.getMsgTimestamp() && mi.getUsec() == message.getUsec()))) {
        ...
    }
    observableEmitter.onComplete();
}
```

crashes at this line : 
MessageInterface mi = messages.get(i);

Any idea how to go about this? I haven't seen anything like this before.

copy of the crash log:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.app.debug, PID: 15675
    io.reactivex.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: Index: 16, Size: 17
      at io.reactivex.internal.functions.Functions$OnErrorMissingConsumer.accept(Functions.java:704)
      at io.reactivex.internal.functions.Functions$OnErrorMissingConsumer.accept(Functions.java:701)
      at io.reactivex.internal.observers.LambdaObserver.onError(LambdaObserver.java:74)
      at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.checkTerminated(ObservableObserveOn.java:276)
      at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.drainNormal(ObservableObserveOn.java:192)
      at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.run(ObservableObserveOn.java:252)
      at io.reactivex.android.schedulers.HandlerScheduler$ScheduledRunnable.run(HandlerScheduler.java:109)
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
    Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 16, Size: 17
      at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
      at com.app.MessageList$8.subscribe(MessageList.java:282)
      at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableCreate.subscribeActual(ObservableCreate.java:40)
      at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10842)
      at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSubscribeOn$SubscribeTask.run(ObservableSubscribeOn.java:96)
      at io.reactivex.Scheduler$DisposeTask.run(Scheduler.java:452)
      at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:61)
      at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:52)
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
      at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:272)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Comment: Posting your logcat would help a lot.

Comment: just posted the crash log. hope that helps?

Comment: done. let me know if that makes sense

Comment: No it does not. All valid indices should be in the 0...16 range for a 17 elements array.

Comment: but it is 0 to 16 : for (int i = 0; i < messages.size(); i++) { (with message.size = 17)

Comment: We're saying the same thing: The error doesn't make sense to me. It should work fine. Unless the object size is not decreased during the loop or by some concurrent use of the same object.

Comment: It's concurrent access - no iterators to protect from concurrent modifications.

Comment: Could you please provide the outer scope of the subscribe method?